# difference between new Class() and new Class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I can't find out in google and in php.net whether there is difference in getting new objects of the class you need using constructions like: `$object = new Class()` and `$object = new Class`. I know there is some difference when you use C++ or Java but does PHP code written like this have some specific differences?

Comment: Try `var_dump()`, is there a difference?

Comment: Did a var_dump on two DateTimes instanciated the way he described : No diff.

Comment: var_dump() has no difference, may be there is something in allocating memory or so... That's the main thing i ask about.